# smarty while-loop error

Tags: smarty, while-loop

The official docs says that smarty has 'while' [support](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.while.tpl) . However I do in template the following:

```
{while $foo > 0}
  {$foo--}
{/while}
```

and I get the following error :

> syntax error: unrecognized tag 'while'
>   (Smarty_Compiler.class.php)

Can you please help with that issue ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using an old version (without `while`) of smarty, that's why you get the error

Answer (score 2):

As @RC said, you are probably using Smarty v2. If you can't upgrade to v3, you'd want to look at [`{section}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl) or maybe [`{foreach}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) for looping.